# Unable to check-in online KLM (AMS-IAD)

Tags: indian-citizens, online-resources, b1-b2-visas, check-in, klm

My friend who is an Indian citizen is unable to check in online in the KLM airlines website. She gets an error similar to somthing like this:

> Unfortunately, it is not possible to check in because we have not yet
>   received confirmation that your ESTA application was approved.
>   Residents of countries under the Visa Waiver Programme need to have
>   ESTA travel authorization for travel to or via the United States

Why would she require an ESTA to travel? She has a valid B1/B2 visa and this is her second trip to the United States.

Comment: It is likely an error in the system, or perhaps in the wording of the error message. If the system doesn't support visa-bearing travelers, she'll just have to check in in person.  (As an Indian citizen, she's not even *eligible* for ESTA, much less required to have one.)

Comment: Ok. But there is no need to panic right?

Comment: @Müller No, she can check in at the airport as usual. If the staff are such noobs that they require an ESTA or even a printed-out confirmation of it (even though Indians cannot even get an ESTA), she has to ask to speak to the supervisor

Comment: Yeah ok. Its a pain then. Most of the good seats would be taken by the time she checks in I guess. And we didn't want to pay for the seats.

Comment: @Müller I know the feeling. She might be able to check in at a kiosk though, and they usually open earlier than the manual check-in

Comment: No worries there. I was unable to check in online for eight years and dozens of trips to the USA. Always checked in at the airport, although usually it took a supervisor, the situation just broke the normal flows. They couldn't figure this situation out: B1/B2 visa despite ESTA eligible and then later a NEXUS card on top of this mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, the ones who designed the check-in system are noobs, which is not limited to KLM's Website.

I had something similar happen to me when trying to check in on a Delta flight JFK-ZRH. It asked me when I would return to Sweden, and when I marked that I wouldn't, I got a message saying I have to check in at the airport.

So, unfortunately your friend will only be able to check in at the airport. She should definitely send a complaint message to KLM though - I sent one to Delta and they acknowledged the issue.